# Android app to test round trip time

Tags: java, android

I m working on an android app for which shows some basic wifi information like signal strength and all. It is also expected to show the network round trip delay. We may do this by using HttpPost and HttpResponse. Below is the piece of code which I have written however I am not able to get the desireed result

```
chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
            chronometer.start();
            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

            HttpPost url = new HttpPost("my url");
            HttpClient roundclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse urlResponse = roundclient.execute(url);
            HttpEntity roundentity = urlResponse.getEntity();
            //InputStream inputStreamdelay = urlResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            //if (null!= roundentity) {
                //strTemp = br.readLine();
            chronometer.stop();
            System.out.println(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            Log.v("time", Double.toString(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()));
```

Comment: Looks like you're blocking the UI thread with the network call `roundclient.execute(url);`  If the UI thread is blocked, your Chronometer view won't be able to draw (drawing happens on the UI thread).  You'll want to do your network call on a background thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot....got your point however as being very new to java, I am not able to convert your suggestion at code level..........the above code I wrote by referring some posts on this forum......can you please guide me with a code segment which I can understand and test inside the "try"

Comment: Take a look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html); the 'Usage' section has a good example.  Also, you may want to read up on threads [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Comment: this seems to be for downloading the content however my goal is to just send the request and receive the first response from only one website and then note down the round trip time. please let me know if I am getting it wrong